# Android Studio's Android device monitor (ADM) is not launching/showing in Windows, but there are no errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

So, I wanted to see if successfully created the database for my application in Android Studio through ADM. It has been 5 minutes and no new window opened. There are no errors it is just not launching, I guess. Even my cursor won't give me a hint if there is it's loading or not. Should I just wait for it to appear or there are things that I should do for ADM to open? My Android Studio Version is 3.0.1 and running it in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"most components of the Android Device Monitor are deprecated in favor of updated tools available in Android Studio 3.0 and higher."

I faced similar problem, I updated the android studio and while searching I found the below link.

After your update, Follow this link
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html

hope this helps :)